# Nested queries results in error 'The multi-part identifier "r.ctripnumber" could not be bound.'

Tags: sql-server, nested

I have two tables that I am querying that contain the following data:

**revenuedtl**

```
ctripnumber   cmethod                   curevenue
-------------------------------------------------
324198        BROKERSANITIZE              65.00
324198        BROKERFUELSURCHARGE        243.35
324198        BROKERBULKWINE             785.00
```

**payrolldtl**

```
ctripnumber      cmethod                   curevenue
------------------------------------------------------
324198           BROKERBULKWINE              628.00
324198           BROKERFUELSURCHARGE         200.96
324198           BROKERSANITIZE               52.00
```

I have written the following queries that sums up the charges as 'Revenue Total' and 'Carrier Total'.

**Sidenote**: I had to write the subtotal queries to overcome some bad DB design issues which created duplicates when I joined the tables. We should be able to disregard this issue.

```
select 
    sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total' 
from 
    (select 
         r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
     from 
         revenuedtl r 
     where 
         r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
         and r.ctripnumber = '324198'
     group by 
         r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod) A
```

Result:

```
Revenue Total
1093.35

select 
    sum(Carrier_Subtotal) as 'Carrier Total' 
from 
    (select p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod, sum(p.curevenue) as Carrier_Subtotal 
     from payrolldtl p 
     where p.cmethod in (select distinct p.cmethod from payrolldtl p) 
       and p.ctripnumber = '324198'
     group by p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod)B
```

Result:

```
Carrier Total
880.96
```

Problem: I want to change the query to return `r.ctripnumber` with the `sum(Revenue_Subtotal)` like this:

```
select
    r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total' 
from 
    (select r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
     from revenuedtl r 
     where r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
     --and r.ctripnumber = '324198'
     group by r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod) A
```

but I get the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "r.ctripnumber" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` is not a valid alias in the outer query:  `select r.ctripnumber,sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total'`

The only table alias that the outer query sees is `A`.

by the way, if you want to do a SUM() in the outer query like you're doing, you'll need to add another GROUP BY in the outer query's context.  But really, I don't see any reason why you need to use an outer/inner query at all.   For just the code you've shown, it isn't gaining you anything.   Maybe it's a simplification of a larger query that needs it?

Comment: Many thanks!!  That was a quick fix.  Now I'm faced with a different issue when I try to pull the data from both queries together in one result.  However, I'll put this in a different post to avoid a long running story.

Comment: @GaryGlasspool Don't try to post code in a comment.   Either edit your question, or ask a new one.